# EditText not wrapping its content

Tags: android

I am trying to create an EditText which toggles its state between read only and write mode.
My XML is as below:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/textArea" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:lines="4"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine">
</EditText>
```

In my code i do the following :

```
textArea = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(com.pravaa.mobile.R.id.textArea);
  //isEditable decides if the EditText is editable or not
 if(!isEditable){
        textArea.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
  }
  //the view is added to a linear layout. 
  addView(textArea);
```

My issue is that the text does not get wrapped. Am i missing out on something? Kindly help me with this. I have also attached an image of my output.

[image: EditText does not exapnd in height]

[image: The text does not wrap]

The text set in the view is "12345678901234567 90123456789012345678901234567890 Nationwide Campaign New"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by removing

```
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

To achieve the non-editable feature I used

```
 setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `setEnabled(false);` ?

Answer (score 9):

I guess that by calling this ...

```
textArea.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

you override the flag InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE. Try calling this instead...

```
textArea.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Comment: i tried setting the type to: textArea.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE); i still have the same result.

Comment: If you use `textArea.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` it doesn't screw up the multilines but I can still type in with the emulator keyboard and the long press menu also still works.
I think the solution for you is tu use `textArea.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: Thats weird. Are you sure you are not changing anything else of the EditText? Here is how I tried it. 
`<EditText android:id="@+id/editText" android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:lines="4" android:text="..." />`
And in the code I just use `editText.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: Hi thank you. Was able to get it working. Now in order try to make the field editable i try setting setFocusable(true); when i click on the corresponding field i am not able to directly type into it. Only when i use the mouse to scroll i am able to type into the field. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Does that mean that the cursor is not in the right position and you have to change it with the trackball? Or do you mean that you can't interact with the `EditText` by using touch-input?

Comment: I was not able to interact with the EditText by using touch-input. I solved it by using setFocusableInTouchMode(true);. Thank you.

Comment: You need to replace TYPE_NULL with TYPE_CLASS_TEXT otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This line will make the text multi-line and will wrap the text

```
textArea.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

You'd probably also want to call **setLines(n)** to set the height of the textArea.

Comment: This (and I tried all the other solutions and they didn't work) solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

with:

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that by using `textArea.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` you remove the `textMultiLine` from your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just set textMultiLine isn't enough. Try this:

```
textArea.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
textArea.setEllipsize(null);
textArea.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Comment: it still give me the same behaviour.. :-( could it be the layout causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What me helped was:

```
edtText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
edtText.setSingleLine(false);
```

It seems that the setSingleline Attribute in the XML file is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` is what got it working for me.